# Curl echo Server response Bash

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to create a bash script that check url from list status code and echo server name from header. I'm actually new.

```
#!/bin/bash
        while read LINE; do
          curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$LINE"
          echo " $LINE" &
          curl -I /dev/null --silent --head | grep -Fi Server "$SERVER"
          echo " $SERVER"
        done < dominios-https
```

I get the following output

```
301 http://example.com
grep: : No such file or directory
```

Comment: Where do you think the value of `SERVER` is set?

Comment: `set -x`  is your friend, to see what's actually happening at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

1) while read LINE can not use last line if text file not ended with new line.

2) You don't set "$SERVER" anywhere, and grep say it

3) Not all servers return "Server:" in headers

try it:

```
scriptDir=$( dirname -- "$0" )
for siteUrl in $( < "$scriptDir/myUrl.txt" )
do
    if [[ -z "$siteUrl" ]]; then break; fi # break line if him empty
    httpCode=$( curl -I -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$siteUrl" )
    echo "HTTP_CODE = $httpCode"
    headServer=$( curl -I --silent --head "$siteUrl" | grep "Server" | awk '{print $2}' )
    echo "Server header = $headServer"
done
```